# Помогите спроектировать базу для модуля тестирования

Tags: база-данных

Всем привет, хочу сделать небольшое веб-приложение для составления опросов, по сути как тест только с выбором одного ответа. Начинаю с проектирования базы данных, и сразу попадаю в ступор, ведь у меня нет конечного количества вопросов, нет конечного количества вариантов ответов... И как быть? Получается не могу статично задать количество полей... У меня идея как бы такая, сделать три поля (основных не считая ID, таймингов и т. П.) типа TEXT, в первое поле заносить в json массив с вопросами, во второй массив с ответами, в третий массив с правильными ответами, а потом на странице как бы перебором массивов выставлять в норм вид... Вот такая идея, как вы считаете, идея норм? Ну вообще мне кажется возможно можно проще, или есть более рациональный способ, поделитесь пожалуйста опытные разработчики, буду очень благодарен дажн ссылке, даже на иностранный ресурс. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Нормализация базы данных:

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/troubleshoot/access/database-normalization-description

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/troubleshoot/access/database-normalization-description

Если говорить о JSON, да и о нетипичном наборе данных, то я бы использовал типизацию данных JSON, точнее типа вопроса/ответа и в зависимости от типа выбирал бы представление и обработку этого вопроса.

Такой вариант позволил бы хранить разные вопросы, ответы, отметки о правильных ответах и т.п. в одном месте и в различных формах.

"небольшое веб-приложение для составления опросов, по сути как тест только с выбором одного ответа" Думайте шире, в меру конечно, и это даст вам ответы на ваши вопросы и возможности для расширения возможностей вашей систем без переписывания всей системы.

Схема примерно такая: ID, name, type, data/settings.

Данные (data) для самого простого вопроса (type = single):

```
{
    question: 'Your question', 
    answers: [
         {name: 'First answer', right: true}, 
         {name: 'Second answer', right: false}
    ]
}
```

Т.е. один вопрос, несколько вариантов ответа, причем у ответа указан флаг правильности или неправильности. По типу single вы уже можете обработать это как вам надо. Причем вы можете не хранить значение неправильного, и в случае его отсутствия считать, что он ложный.

Расширим тип (supermultiple), например, может быть несколько перефразированных вопросов, возможных правильных ответов несколько, а также будут стоять ограничения по количеству видимых вариантов ответа.

```
{
    questions: ['Your question', 'Your second question'], 
    answers: [
       {name: 'First answer', right: true}, 
       {name: 'Second answer', right: true}, 
       {name: 'Third answer', right: false}
    ], 
    visibleAnswers: 2
}
```

Как видите, список полей поменялся, а это можно продолжать очень долго:

- вопрос с вводом ответа, причем несколько правильных (по-разному пишутся, например, БД,
  база данных, база);
- вопрос с вводом перечислений;
- вопрос с примером,
  где для каждого вопроса соответствует свой ответ и т.д.